# Sharepoint Cascading Dropdowns - Show Default Value from List B in List A

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, cascadingdropdown

I have a sharepoint list setup for employees to make reservations for a training session. There is also a linked list where count against each session is updated when someone books a session, which has been completed using Nintex Workflows. So in effect:

**List A Cols**
*Staff Name - Session Details*

**List B Cols**
*Session Details - Session Booking Count*

What I am trying to do is have the Session Booking Count shown on Newform of List A if user selects a specific session, and to write a validation to show error if Count > 10.

I have tried to setup a cascading dropdown option using jquery, and this does show the count of each session, however default value is coming as "(none)". User has to click on the drop down and select the count figure manually.

Is there a way to change this so that by default the count is shown?

```
<script src="https://team.global.hsbc/sites/GSCGMOpsComms/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://team.global.hsbc/sites/GSCGMOpsComms/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
{
   $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns(
   {
      relationshipList: "GCB6 Promo Process Counter List",
      relationshipListParentColumn: "SessionName",
      relationshipListChildColumn: "SessionCount",
      parentColumn: "Session",
      childColumn: "Session Bookings",
      debug: true
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using nintex forms? if yes, these have ootb functionality to configure cascading dropdowns, if using regular jquery based custom form, make sure, you set up/select the value of `session count` based on selected session in `$document.ready()`;

Comment: are you working on a custom form using jquery, javascript/html?

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider Unfortunately this particular site has not been enabled with nintex forms, only workflows. I have updated the code I have used in the original post. Could you have a look and advise how to update?

Comment: can't find the code

Comment: just added it in

Comment: version shows v2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

if single value is returned from child list column e.g. `booking count` try making `booking count` (lookup) column as `Required` from list column settings in parent list. This should remove `none' option from your dropdown.

for `decimal places` issue, *change the column settings to return zero decimal places*:
[image]

Comment: That worked :) .. 2 related questions 
1) the value is coming as "1.00000000000000" - can this be reduced to show without decimal point?
2) lookup does not allow column validation?

Comment: please accept the answer if this worked. and check column settings for your session count column. if its number, there is a setting to show number without decimal points

Comment: check my edited answer if that works for decimal places issue.

Comment: SessionCount in the looked up list is set to 0 decimal places. However when called into main list as a lookup column, its returning all the additional 0's.

Comment: hack-ish solution but you could make it a single line of text variable then. in your nintex workflow that updates this column, you could first convert the count to string and then update the item.